# Establish opt-out and opt-in flow for SMSes from Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, servicecloud, sms, unsubscribe

**Premise**:

We are sending messages to Customers from Salesforce Service by calling marketing cloud Transactional API. We are using Marketing cloud only as gateway and, templates for SMSes and Emails, are all sent as content in the API call payload. Once the message is sent, we write the logs in the Log object in Service cloud with messagekey, status etc.

**Problem** :

We want to implement an opt-in and opt-out flow for SMSes messages so that clients can opt-out and also see STATUS "Opt-out" in the Log object for passengers that has opted out(if the message was undelivered because of opt out status).
What could be the best possible approach to implement this scenario.

Comment: For opting out, do you have your STOP Keyword configured?

Comment: Not Yet, we will configure that as a first step.

Comment: How are you writing the logs in Service Cloud? Are you using Marketing Cloud to do that? Do I understand correctly that you want to log each undelivered message there as well?

Comment: If you want to opt people out for all (future) keywords , then look into setting up a mobile suppression list and adding people to it on unsub.

Comment: @Rafał Wolsztyniak No we are writing the logs with Apex in Service Cloud. We do use Event notification service to send the response to service Cloud and then we update the status of Log object to sent/bounced/opened.And yes, we do want show in the Log that message was undelivered because of opt out.